# Import 3D textured object into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I want to import a 3D mesh which is exported from Photoscan. I tried with Collada export (.dae) and 3ds models (.3ds).

I created a global scene in ArcGIS and imported the file with the function "import 3D objects", and defined a file database in order to put the multipatch features in.

Now, the imported object has a solid color (see printscreen below) but I want to add the texture to the 3D object (which was exported in JPEG from Photoscan). The function "replace the multipatch" does not work, as it used to with ArcScene.

[image]